# Custom NER using spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train a custom NER model to identify musical artists. The challenge is that I only have the names of the artists without complete sentences containing those names. To address this issue, I am appending additional text after the artist names. For instance, "artistname" is transformed into "artistname has released good music in the last year." Subsequently, I convert the data to the JSON format, as per the documentation.

```
['daniele leoni', 'yogesh samsi', 'fadagad', 'dream your dream', 'rodrigo mozart', 'kelly finnigan', 'floor cry', 'martin solveig', 'vayu', 'angerfist']
```

is converted to

```
[{'text': 'daniele leoni is so good', 'entities': [(0, 13, 'ARTIST')]}, {'text': 'fadagad is a renowned musician', 'entities': [(0, 7, 'ARTIST')]}.....
```

This is not tagging the artists properly at all. Any idea how I can train a custom model when I have just the entities, not sentences containing the entities. Thanks